# MySql valor decimal incorreto na view

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, mvc

Eu não sei por que o número 9937.77 armazenado no MySql como Decimal(12,2) exibe 9 milhões nas views
1.00 exibe 100 (1,00 é o correto)
5.77 exibe 577 (5,77 é o correto)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei

```
DisplayFor(m => m.MyNumber)
Model.MyNumber.toString("n2")
Model.MyNumber.toString("C")
```

MySql Decimal(12,2)

```
Default collation utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
Default chartset utf8mb4
```